# Python Pip Install SSL Error 749

Tags: python, ssl, pip

- Pip version:9.0.1
- Python version:3.6.1
- Operating system:Win10

#### Description:

I'm trying to set python libraries up in my corporate laptop but run into SSL error 749 when running pip -install for any library. I have tried several suggestions from other posts but they didn't work. I guess the error code is slightly different.

Can someone guide me how to resolve the SSL issue?

#### What I've run:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pandas

Collecting pandas
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

Comment: can you try it using pip3? pip3 install pandas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: nope pip3 same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify cert with this param.

```
pip --cert /etc/ssl/certs/FOO_Root_CA.pem install pandas
```

See: [Docs » Reference Guide » pip](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pip/#cmdoption--cert)

If specifying your company's root cert doesn't work maybe the cURL one will work: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

You must use a PEM file and not a CRT file. If you have a CRT file you will need to convert the file to PEM

Also check: [SSL Cert Verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

**OR**

`pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org pandas`

Comment: i've tried with --trusted-host same ssl error 749 as well.
Exact same error returned.

Comment: @RyanT : Try this one : `pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org  pythonPackage`

Comment: yep tried this as well, it prompts for a 'User for rosydpx1:' and login, i tried entering my credentials and it ended up showing error " could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pythonPackage (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pythonPackage"

Comment: You are using windows so ,Uninstall everything Python and every other python packages and download and install Anaconda .It comes along with every python package you need.[link]( https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a very frustrating experience in a corporate environment when you are trying to get something done.

An alternative you can try as a last resort is:

- downwload the whl file directly from pypi
- place in the site-packages folder of the python env you want to use
- run pip install `<name of whl file>`

If pip encounters any requirements not met, it will try to get via ssl and you'll get the same error.  However you can perform the above for that whl as well.

I did this for matplotlib.  I already had numpy and most other requirements, but I had to do similar for kiwisolver and cycler packagers.

You can even install pip this way.

This is a very manual and error prone solution (tedious if dependency list is long) but can help you move forward while your IT guys try to figure things out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
yum install -y libxml2 libxml2-devel  libxslt libxslt-devel  libffi-devel  python-devel openssl-devel
pip install pyopenssl
pip install parsel 
pip install twisted
```